# How can I determine and then plot a confidence bands in QuantilePlot?

Tags: plotting

Does anyone know if its possible to plot a confidence band in `QuantilePlot`? I haven't been able to find any documentation for this, or a previous example on here.

At the moment the only way I can think of doing this is via simulation or bootstrapping, which I'd like to avoid.

---

I've made an attempt based in some of the resources posted in the comments.  This give a simultaneous confidence band:

```
n = 64;
X = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n];
μ = Mean[X];
σ = StandardDeviation[X];
α = 0.05 (* For a 100(1-α)% simultaneous confidence band *)
k = Sqrt[Log[2/α]/(2 n)]  (* Good when n > 35 *)
Show[
        {
            QuantilePlot[X, NormalDistribution[Mean[X], StandardDeviation[X]],ImageSize->Automatic->200, LabelStyle->12, PlotStyle->Red],
            ListPlot[Table[{x, InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] - k]}, {x, X}], PlotRange->All],
            ListPlot[Table[{x, InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 1/Length[X] Length[Select[X, # <= x &]] + k]}, {x, X}], PlotRange->All]
        }, PlotRange->All
    ]
```

[image: QQ plot and simultaneous confidence band]

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111288/confidence-bands-for-qq-line and https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/787/lectures-quantiles2-handouts.pdf.

Comment: Nice. I'll have a bash and try my own implementation.

Comment: @JimB I've had a go, and it "looks" like I'm heading in the right direction, but something feels wrong bout it. I think I'm missing a detail or misunderstood an aspect. Do you think you could prompt me in the right direction?

Comment: Sure. I’ll work on it tonight.

Comment: My only real edit to your code was adding in the approximate value of `k`.  You did all the rest and you should write up your own answer.  For sample sizes less than 35 there are tables for `k`:  http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~lipschultz/cs1538/prob-table_KS.pdf.  And, of course, there are several other approaches to obtain simultaneous and pointwise confidence bands.  (The pointwise confidence bands are not adjusted for multiple comparisons.)

Comment: Thanks for this! Do similar tables exist for other tests, like a Shapiro-Wilks test for example?

Comment: Table D5 in https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2015-10/documents/monitoring_appendd_1997.pdf gives the critical values for sample sizes up to 50.